# What to do if previous employer is stating they only give electronic W2’s but I didn’t sign up for it?

Tags: taxes, w2

I worked for a restaurant last year it ended pretty badly. I didn’t ask or ever want an electric w2. We are well past the last day i should have received it in the mail. I emailed the company and was told that they only do it electronically due to some issues with fraud in previous years. Now the employee portal they use shows I don’t have an active account and to contact my employer, exactly what I was hoping to avoid. Isnt this illegal somehow??

Comment: Do you have your last paystub of the year? It will have a lot of useful info on it. Were your paystubs paper? Did you have direct deposit? But yeah, they are obligated to settle this with you very quickly.

Comment: Nothing illegal has happened _yet_, certainly. Call back and ask for help retrieving the information.

Comment: Is it illegal to only provide electronic W2, probably not, you kept all your pay stubs?

Comment: Or you could contact your employer.

Comment: It seems not well thought out for an employer to provide necessary information through a system that former employees cannot access. Further, what if you had died? Someone would need to get the info to file your taxes (yes, you still have your obligation for that year). Mailing to your last known address is one way.

Comment: I don't know the legality or illegality of your specific situation, but your employer is bound by law to furnish you with your W-2.  If they're stating that they only furnish it electronically, and you're unable to access it via that method, then it stands to reason that they need to assist you in gaining access to it. I would simply contact them, explain the situation, and ask them how you can access it. It may be as simple as them reaching out to the payroll company to grant you access.

Comment: @HappyIdiot Dead people are obligated to file their taxes? What is the penalty for not doing so?

Comment: @rhoonah your estate is 'unconsecrated' and can be stuck in limbo for a long time. Some people call the IRS vampires, but I wouldn't go that far. They all seem very nice.

Comment: Filing outstanding taxes is part of the process of settling the estate, usually handled by the executor or someone they hire. Yes, it's "death and taxes", not death _or_ taxes.

Answer (score 5):

Email them again. Then, call them. Remind them of your request and tell them that the web site "shows I don’t have an active account and to contact my employer". They'll either reset your account and give you a temporary password, or they'll mail you a paper W2.

Glitches like these happen all the time. Never assume maliciousness when an innocent mistake could simply be the cause.

> Isnt this illegal somehow??

It's illegal not to share the W2, yes.

But if you're unwilling to email them a second time, that's 100% on you. You're not a child anymore. If there is a glitch somewhere, you need to tell them about it.

Comment: Consider sending a certified letter as well. You need proof that you've requested the W-2 and have provided your correct address. Both answers are great advice.

Comment: @DogBoy37 To be honest, that kind of "certified" is cost that is unnecessary if you have easy access to the restaurant. I wouldn't bother wasting money doing this unless you're building a legal case, or if they're genuinely hard to get to (e.g.: moved out of state).

Comment: @Nelson I am thinking about the CYA of dealing with the IRS down the road if the restaurant is unresponsive. Always better to have proof that you tried multiple times to get the W-2. Hopefully it is not needed. Certified Letter costs $4.40.

Comment: @DogBoy37, Well, it does look like they respond to their email, so sending a certified letter may be overkill right now.

Answer (score 2):

As Stephan answered, you need to ask them again. If they don't give you the W2 immediately, then you can follow the IRS instructions for this situation. https://www.irs.gov/filing/if-you-dont-get-a-w-2-or-your-w-2-is-wrong

Your employer is required to send the W2 before February 1st. If you don't have your W2 by the end of February, you can contact the IRS and they will tell you what to do next. The IRS wants you to have that document, so they will help you get it.

Comment: This is probably the answer OP wants, not only because it's official IRS policy, but it allows OP to avoid further contact with the former employer.

Comment: @Theodore, Yes, it does seem like this would be the preferred solution by the OP, but at the same time, contacting the IRS, before actually emailing the restaurant that they can't login anymore, would seem needlessly passive aggressive.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, I agree. That's why I advised them to give the employer one more chance to provide the document. If the employer is abrasive (or abusive), then I would advise contacting them through e-mail. That gives you time to choose your words rather than speaking while dealing with negative emotions. It also means you will have a written record of the employer's response if they respond by email. That way they can't pull, "I never said that."